# How do I best convert source paths in a linux ELF file to debug the ELF file on Windows

Tags: debugging, arm, elf, u-boot, cortex-m

I am planning to run U-boot on an ARM based (Cortex-R5 BIG ENDIAN) embedded system.
U-Boot will run as a second level bootloader on top of a 1st level bootloader
developed using IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM (EWARM).
U-Boot is built on a Linux host computer.
The first level bootloader is developed on a Windows host computer.

I just managed to download the U-Boot ELF file using EWARM but there is no source debugging.
Have not copied the source files, but the ELF file of course contains linux style paths.

**Is there any tool that converts an ELF file with linux style paths
to an ELF file with Windows style path?**

"objcopy --only-keep-debug foo foo.dbg" takes a full ELF file
and copies just the debug stuff to foo.dbg
objcopy --strip-debug foo then strips the ELF file.
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=foo.dbg foo adds the connection to the debug info.
No objcopy option to convert paths as far as I can tell.

**Is there any tool which copies a full directory tree, to NTFS handling symbolic links?**

Since this is only for source level debug, making duplicates
instead of following the links would be OK.
My best idea is to copy the file system over the network using SAMBA.
Have not tried, but I suspect SAMBA would ignore the links and just make duplicates.

The Windows computer is connected to a company network and the VPN connection
disables all other networks, so I have to use a third computer for this...
Maybe I could SAMBA mount the linux machine on itself....
Ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any tool which copies a full directory tree, to NTFS handling symbolic links?

You have two options:

1. Copy the directory to a FAT partition. Symbolic links will be replaced by the actual files. Both Linux and Windows can read and write FAT.
2. If you are on the same computer: Mount the NTFS partition in Linux. If Windows uses bitlocker you will need the complete key (the PIN is not enough).